# Csv file reading in java

Tags: java, csv

My program is to read values from a csv file.I am to totally confused with the following part of code in my program
 `reader.readHeaders()` 
and 
`reader.readRecord()`(these methods are undescribed in my eclipse)
methods in java....Because it showing me errors. Is there any jar files need to be added to my program?

```
try {
    System.out.println("file name"+fileName);
    CsvReader products = new CsvReader("categories/"+fileName);        
    products.readHeaders(); //I'm getting an error here

    while (products.readRecord()) { //I'm also getting an  error here
       //code is here...
    }
```

The jarfiles that I already added is that

1. `opencsv-2.2.jar`
2. `javacsv.jar`

Comment: Which errors does it give?

Comment: there is no template proposals showing there for reader.readHeaders() and  reader.readRecord().Only showing is readAll() and readNext().

Comment: Did you use maven to add  opencsv? If you did its not gonna be a jar problem. I used this in the past and worked like expected.

Comment: If file its excel file ou can use apache poi api library

Comment: @Jack consider using maven as already mentioned. Could sound to me like you have the wrong version of the .jar-file.

Comment: Ok let me try(for using maven)...

Comment: Per the code, I would guess it is based on project [javacsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/). Those methods are showing in the [documentation](http://javacsv.sourceforge.net/com/csvreader/CsvReader.html) in that website. I would suggest to go to that link and download the latest JAR file and associate it to your project in Eclipse. It may solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a method from the wrong library. `readHeaders()` is a method in `com.csvreader.CsvReader`. But you are using [OpenCSV](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv/5.5.2) (`com.opencsv.CSVReader`), for which the method is `readNextSilently()`.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just a quick tip; you can surround text with backticks (`) to display it in a monospace font, which is helpful for readability, particularly with code.